# Combining 3 separate sql queries into one result

Tags: sql, t-sql

So I have three sql queries requesting 3 different things
but I want to be able to combine them into 1 table so that each query appears in each column

these are the queries:

```
select b.name, count(*)
from account a join branch b
on a.open_branch_id = b.branch_id
group by b.name;

select b.name, count(*)
from employee e join branch b
on e.assigned_branch_id = b.branch_id
group by b.name;

select b.name, count(*)
from customer c join branch b
on c.city = b.city
group by b.name;
```

i don't know how to combine them so query 1 will appear in 1 column, query 2 in the 2nd column, and query 3 in the third column.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: When selecting an answer, please consider which one gave you the needed information first in time.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, you want to join your results based on your name field from each query?  Assuming each have the same names, you can do this with `JOINs` and subqueries.  Here is a simplified version (replace the subqueries with yours above):

```
select t1.name, t1.cnt, 
       t2.name as t2name, t2.cnt as t2cnt, 
       t3.name as t3name, t3.cnt as t3cnt
from 
  (select name, count(1) cnt
   from t1
   group by name) t1 join 
  (select name, count(1) cnt
   from t2
   group by name) t2 on t1.name = t2.name join 
  (select name, count(1) cnt
   from t3
   group by name) t3 on t1.name = t3.name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58d8c/3)

---

Edit, given your comments, it appears this is what you might be looking for:

```
select b.name, 
  a.acctcnt, e.empcnt, c.citycnt
from branch b
  left join (
    select count(1) acctcnt, open_branch_id
    from account 
    group by open_branch_id
    ) a on a.open_branch_id = b.branch_id 
  left join (
    select count(1) empcnt, assigned_branch_id
    from employee
    group by assigned_branch_id
    ) e on e.assigned_branch_id = b.branch_id 
  left join (
    select count(1) citycnt, city
    from customer 
    group by city
    ) c on c.city = b.city
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aef9f/1)

Comment: the first column is a list of accounts at each branch. the second column is the number of employees working at each branch and the thrid column is the number of customers that reside in the same city of each particular branch

Comment: @karmalaa -- so you want 3 columns -- branch name, count employees in the branch, and count of customers in the same city as the branch?  What about your first query -- count of accounts?  Perhaps you want 4 columns -- branch name, emp cnt, cust cnt, acct cnt?

Comment: well 4, the first column is the branch name, 2nd is number of accts opened at branch, 3rd is number of employees at each branch, 4th is number of customers in the same city as the branch. I'm wondering if there's a way to nest the joins simply since the queries individually are virtually the same format

Comment: If restrictive `WHERE` conditions are applied to the `Branch` table, could the engine still fully perform some or all of the subqueries (not filtering them)?

Comment: cool, this is along the lines of what i was trying to do initially. thanks for everyone's help

Comment: @ErikE -- good question, but from what I can tell, since the tables only join on the branch id or city fields, adding `where` criteria to restrict which branches were returned would not change the count results.  The count should be exclusive of the results (from my interpretation of the joins/tables).  If for example, branches could have multiple cities, then all bets would be off...  Hopefully this will help the OP get going in the right direction though.

Comment: @karmalaa -- np, glad we could help!

Comment: @sgeddes I think you misunderstood. Consider if there are 10,000 branches, but you put conditions on `Branch` to return only 20. Of course the individual counts for each of those 20 won't be any different, but there are 9,980 sets of counts that aren't needed. Will the engine compute the 9,980 unneeded values?

Comment: @ErikE -- In my experience, `correlated subqueries` come with a pretty big cost and I generally prefer to stay away from them (although they can serve a purpose in certain situations).  If adding conditional criteria to the query is required, including those criteria in the `noncorrelated subqueries` would arguably have the best performance.  However, depending on the indices and criteria in question, full table scans could result regardless.  In other words (as usual with performance), it really depends.  Kind regards.

Comment: @sgeddes In my experience, in SQL Server 2005 and up, it is a myth that correlated subqueries come with any extra cost. The query engine has repeatedly properly understood my query intent and performed relational algebra to efficiently retrieve the data. It seems very plainly clear to me that calculating the 3 counts for ALL the 10,000 branches via a whole table scan, then discarding all but 20 of those, is going to be WAY costlier than collecting 20 counts one at a time with seeks. This does depend on indexes. But please don't make the blanket statement against correlated subqueries any more.

Comment: @ErikE -- I appreciate your reply, but to say using correlated subqueries won't come with any additional cost isn't completely accurate (especially if indices aren't present, or use incorrectly).  Rewriting correlated subqueries with Joins is generally the preferable solution from my experience (db agnostic).  I do agree the optimizers have improved over the years with all RDBMS, and they can quite often infer identical execution plans (as in this case if I'm not mistaken).  However, the real answer, as it always is in regards to performance, is that it just depends.

Comment: It does depend, but that's different from what you said earlier--a blanket statement. I will again and categorically say that there is nothing inherently slow about correlated subqueries--unless you're using MySQL in which case you have much bigger problems (HAR). You said they come with a big cost; that is what I am objecting to; that's my story and I'm sticking to it.

Comment: P.S. You can't add the conditions to the non-correlated subqueries if the conditions are on columns present only in outer tables! In the edge case where repeating conditions in the subquery will work, you're still increasing complexity needlessly. I used to think the same way as you but that was about 5 years ago. I work with SQL Server 2005 and up now...

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this (SQL Server 2005 and up):

```
SELECT
   B.Name,
   B.OtherColumnsIfYouLike,
   ACount = IsNull(ACount, 0),
   ECount = IsNull(E.ECount, 0),
   CCount = IsNull(C.CCount, 0)
FROM
   dbo.Branch B
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT ACount = Count(*)
      FROM dbo.Account A
      WHERE B.Branch_ID = A.Open_Branch_ID
   ) A
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT ECount = Count(*)
      FROM dbo.Employee E
      WHERE B.Branch_ID = E.Assigned_Branch_ID
   ) E
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT CCount = Count(*)
      FROM dbo.Customer C
      WHERE B.City = C.City
   ) C
;
```

Any query you use needs to pay attention to whether there may be no results at all for that branch name. Using `INNER JOIN` (or just `JOIN`) will exclude these instead of properly showing `0`.

Using your existing queries intact will work like the following, but won't perform as well:

```
SELECT
   Name = Coalesce(A.Name, E.Name, C.Name),
   ACount = IsNull(ACount, 0),
   ECount = IsNull(E.ECount, 0),
   CCount = IsNull(C.CCount, 0)
FROM
   (
      select b.name, ACount = Count(*)
      from account a join branch b on a.open_branch_id = b.branch_id
      group by b.name
   ) A
   FULL JOIN (
      select b.name, ECount = Count(*)
      from employee e join branch b on e.assigned_branch_id = b.branch_id
      group by b.name
   ) E ON A.Name = E.Name
   FULL JOIN (
      select b.name, CCount = Count(*)
      from customer c join branch b on c.city = b.city group by b.name
   ) C ON IsNull(A.Name, E.Name) = C.Name
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name column is going to have the same values, you can join them like this. From your query however, it seems that the names you are showing are of branches, employees and customers.

```
select b.name as Name, count(*) as [Count] into #Result1 from account a join branch b on a.open_branch_id = b.branch_id group by b.name;

select b.name  as Name, count(*) as [Count] into #Result2 from employee e join branch b on e.assigned_branch_id = b.branch_id group by b.name;

select b.name  as Name, count(*) as [Count] into #Result3 from customer c join branch b on c.city = b.city group by b.name;

select r1.name,
    r1.[Count],
    r2.[Count],
    r3.[Count],
from #Result1 as r1
        left join #Result2 as r2 on r1.name = r2.name
        left join #Result3 as r3 on r1.name = r3.name

drop table #Result1
drop table #Result2
drop table #Result3
```

Comment: This does not work, what is #Result1 is missing a name. branch is the only table guaranteed to have all the names.

Comment: Same problem -- if account table does not have a name value that is in branch this will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the fastest:

```
with a as
(
  select open_branch_id as b_id, count(*) as a_count
  from account a 
  group by open_branch_id 
), e as
(
  select assigned_branch_id as b_id, count(*) as e_count
  from employee e 
  group by assigned_branch_id
), c as
(
  select b.branch_id as b_id, count(*) as c_count
  from customer c join branch b
  on c.city = b.city
  group by b.name
)
select b.name, a.a_count, e.e_count, c.c_count
from branch b
left join a on a.b_id = b.branch_id 
left join e on e.b_id = b.branch_id 
left join c on c.b_id = b.branch_id 
order by b.name
```

Comment: I would not recommend joining on the branch names -- what if different branch ids have the same name?  I'd also consider removing the joins from the common table expressions, just grouping by the branch ids, and then joining on the branch ids instead of the names.

Comment: @sgeddes If there are duplicate branch names then everything has already gone to hell because he is grouping by branch name in his sample queries. Moving `branch` out of the CTEs was definitely required for better performance.

Comment: Yep you are both right, I spaced removing the joins out of CTEs -- fixed now.  Thanks.